# Any php code to make embed code of video?

Tags: php, jquery

I Want a php code to turn a youtube/dailymotion/vimeo/metacafe... URL into an EMBEDABLE code so i can show it using `echo` , it is really hard to read the API of every website, so i'm wondering if there is a class or code to do this.

Note: if there isn't anyone, then maybe a jQuery facebox alternative who supports more than youtube.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

it's not so difficult.

youtube link is like this `http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XXXX` where `XXXX` is the video ID.

and this is the code for embedding the video

```
<object width="480" height="385">
<param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/XXXX&hl=en_US&fs=1&">
</param>
<param name="allowFullScreen" value="true">
</param>
<param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always">
</param>
<embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/XXXX&hl=en_US&fs=1&" 
type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" 
allowfullscreen="true" width="480" height="385"></embed>
</object>
```

you only need to parse (ie. using php) the youtube links and then insert the found id insted of XXXX